# Can we use `if` or `guard` instead of `switch` on an enum to extract a value?

Tags: swift, if-statement, enums, swift3

I defined an enum and I made a computed property to extract the value associated with one of the cases. I wrote this computation with a `switch`:

```
enum NetworkResult<T> {
    case json(T)
    case error(Error)

    var error: Error? {
        switch self {
        case .error(let error):
            return error
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to achieve the same computed property without any `switch` keyword?** (for instance, using an `if let` construct?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum NetworkResult<T> {
    case json(T)
    case error(Error)

    var error: Error? {
        if case let .error(error) = self {
            return error
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

        guard case let .error(error) = self else {
            return nil
        }

        return error
```

Comment: oh, `if case` and `guard case`, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Juggling with suggested `if case` construct from Peter Cheng, I actually found multiple ways to write it.

By having `let` outside:

```
var error: Error? {
    if case let .error(error) = self {
        return error
    }
    return nil
}
```

By having `let` inside:

```
var error: Error? {
    if case .error(let error) = self {
        return error
    }
    return nil
}
```

And the guard equivalents...

By having `let` outside:

```
var error: Error? {
    guard case let .error(error) = self else {
        return nil
    }
    return error
}
```

By having `let` inside:

```
var error: Error? {
    guard case .error(let error) = self else {
        return nil
    }
    return error
}
```

The last one is my personal favorite syntax of the four solutions.